# Update info in mysql using _POST

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, sql-update

I have this code that does not do anything but add to my database and only adds the item ounces and retail price.  any ideas on where i am going wrong?

--update.php---

```
<?php

        session_start(); // start session cookies
        require("Login.class.php"); // pull in file
        $login = new Login; // create object login

        $login->authorize(); // make user login
?>




<style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:#42520e; color: #f0cb01;

        }
        th {background: URL(http://www.athenahealth.com/_img/boxes/carousel_bg.png);}
        p {color:blue;}
        a:link {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: underline; }
        a:active {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: underline; }
        a:visited {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: underline; }
        a:hover {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: none; }
</style>

<?php
        $retail=$_REQUEST['retail'];
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $upc=$_REQUEST['upc'];
        $ounces=$_REQUEST['ounces'];
        define("HOST", "localhost");

        $retail=$_REQUEST['retail'];
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $upc=$_REQUEST['upc'];
        $ounces=$_REQUEST['ounces'];


?>
Admin Panel to Update Keywords
<hr>

    <table>
            <tr><td valign="top"><br /><br />
            <td>    
                    Your are editing information for Product #: <b><? echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?></b>
                    <form method="post" action="update_ac.php">
                            <table>         <tr><br /></tr>
                                    <tr><td>  Product #:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?>">* Enter Keyword as it currently appears<br></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>">* Enter New Information<br></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> Suggested Retail:</td><td> <input type="text" name="retail" id="retail" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['retail']; ?>">* New Phone Number<br></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> Ounces: </td><td> <input type="text" name="ounces" id="ounces" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['ounces']; ?>">* Enter new block description here. <br></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td> UPC: </td><td> <input type="text" name="upc" id="upc" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['upc']; ?>">* Enter new block description here. <br></td></tr>

                                    <tr><td> </td><td align="left"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Data"></td></tr>
                            </table>
                    </form>
            </td></tr>
    </table>                <br />
<a href="index.php">Add Keyword</a> | <a href="../admin">Back to search form</a> | 


<?php 
       echo '<pre>'; 
        print($retail); 
        echo '</pre>'; 
?> 




<a href="index.php?action=clear_login">logout</a>
</body>
```

and this is the update link that it uses and carries it over to the update_ac.php

```
 <?php

    session_start(); // start session cookies
    require("Login.class.php"); // pull in file
    $login = new Login; // create object login

    $login->authorize(); // make user login
    ?>

<style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:#42520e; color: #f0cb01;

        }
        th {background: URL(http://www.athenahealth.com/_img/boxes/carousel_bg.png);}
        p {color:blue;}
        a:link {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: underline; }
        a:active {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: underline; }
        a:visited {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: underline; }
        a:hover {color: #f0cb01; text-decoration: none; }
</style>

<?php
        $retail=$_REQUEST['retail'];
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $upc=$_REQUEST['upc'];
        $ounces=$_REQUEST['ounces'];


        define("HOST", "localhost");

        $retail=$_REQUEST['retail'];
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $upc=$_REQUEST['upc'];
        $ounces=$_REQUEST['ounces'];


        // Database user
        define("DBUSER", "root");

        // Database password
        define("PASS", "Password!");

        // Database name
        define("DB", "SnyderLanceSku");

        ############## Make the mysql connection ###########

        $conn = mysql_connect(HOST, DBUSER, PASS) or  die('Could not connect !<br />Please contact the site\'s administrator.');

        $db = mysql_select_db(DB) or  die('Could not connect to database !<br />Please contact the site\'s administrator.');

        mysql_query("UPDATE products SET UPC='$upc', Name='$name', Item_Ounces='$ounces' WHERE UPC='$upc' ") or die (mysql_error());  
?>
<table>
        <tr><td valign="top"><br /><br />
        <td>    
                <table>  <tr><b>Data Updated Successfully</b></tr>       
                        <tr><td>  Keyword:  </td><td><? echo $id; ?><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td> Block?: </td><td><? echo $name; ?><br></td></tr>
                        <tr><td> Phone #:</td><td><?php echo $upc; ?><br> </td></tr>
                        <tr><td> Reason: </td><td><? echo $retail; ?></td></tr>
                        <tr><td> Reason: </td><td><? echo $ounces; ?></td></tr>

                </table>
        </form>
        </td></tr>
</table>

<a href="./">Go Back</a>
```

I'm not really sure where to look here... any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is both scripts.  It almost works correct.  ONly thing now is it is not updating the correct row.  its ADDING a new row instead of updating on id or in this case updating on UPC

Comment: Are you sure this is a POST request? You seem to be passing data through the URL? Isn't this mean't to be a GET request? Also please stop using MySQL and start using something like MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Use $_GET not $_POST

Comment: I wonder if there is wrong variable in `where` clause, how ounce and price adds in database and why `mysql_error();` not showing any error?

Comment: @Shehary because it's a PHP issue, as an undefined variable and not having error reporting enabled.

Comment: I attempted the answer below but still not working correct.  Its only posting the retail price and ounces still.  I change to _GET but that did nothing.

Comment: I have updated my code and using just one update in the mysql but that is still not working at all.  Im lost.

Comment: @Script47 I deleted my comments about the OP's variables not matching, which was changed/fixed in an edit he did.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, I'm quite new to this site, I'm not sure if you mean I should delete my comment too, but I have done.

Comment: @Script47 no, I wasn't implying you delete your comment. However, comments deemed irrelevant in this thread should be deleted, as they take up room no longer relevant.

Comment: `$_GET['name']` and your input bears `name="Name"` so you should have gotten an undefined index notice there. `name` does not equal `Name`. Variables are case-sensitive, remember that. Same for the other inputs. `UPC` and `upc`. So, double check everything. POST/GETs the whole 9 yds. You can always play it safe and use `$_REQUEST` instead of POSTs and GETs.

Comment: @Script47 see above comment to the OP, that'll give you a good idea as to what's going on, or "not". ;-)

Comment: then this `value="<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>"` using `name="Product #"` for your input as the name attribute; not good. Using the wrong name for one thing, plus it's also an invalid name also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- how's my answer now?

Comment: @Script47 it's better but I can't say for certain if that is the full solution. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but let's wait and see what the OP has to say and should be notified that you updated your answer. Will upvote though, as you have signaled many errors in the code.

Comment: @David do you not have a constraint on any of your columns? preferably an AI or primary key. Plus, why are you using `session_start();`? I don't see any session arrays, so you can delete all of those if you're not using it.

Comment: using the primary key fixed all my issue now.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: @David another happy ending. you're welcome and consider accepting the answer given below as he too mentioned the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with this code, from the code you've provided it doesn't seem as though you're sending `POST` requests rather you're sending `GET` requests as you're passing them through the URL. So first thing, change your `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Also your query is wrong.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `products` SET ".implode(", ", $update)."WHERE Product_sku = '$ID'";
```

It should be,

```
$sql = "UPDATE `products` SET ".implode(", ", $update)."WHERE Product_sku = '$id'";
```

I don't see in your code a `$ID` variable, but I do see a `$id` variable. So you need to change that too.

**Edit 1**

Also, turn on `error reporting` to make debugging easier.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

**Edit 2**

As Fred said, you're mistyping when trying to get data from HTML to PHP.

In your *product* input you set the name value to `Product` as you do with the `Name` input too. Yet in your PHP you're doing `$name=$_GET['name'];` when it should be `$name=$_GET['Name'];`.

You should adopt a familiar naming convention such as camelCase which will make it harder to make these errors which are hard to spot. I use the [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) coding conventions personally. So try to adopt one and stick to it.

Another thing, because you never posted your form earlier I suggested you use `$_GET`, however for certain things (such as the form data) you should change it back to `$_POST` as your form `method="post"`.

**Edit 3**

You should also get in to the habit of checking if variables actually contain a value and are correctly set, this is known as validation. I would personally check if the submit button has been pressed (`if (isset($_POST['yourSubmitButtonNameValue']))` then validate the rest of the fields within that if statement. This way, you know the input you're adding in to your database is valid.

Comment: @David what about the `POST` requests to `GET`?

Comment: I tried that as well... No go.  I have a feeling its in my mysql somewhere ... im just not seeing it.  Its posting SOME information... Just not all.... And I want it to update on id but its ADDING to my DB.

Comment: Great thanks.  I updated my code .  Almost working.  It is adding all information to DB now except i want it to UPDATE as i am teling it to on UPC.

Comment: @David I'm baffled myself at how it is adding a row, do you a primary key (unique identifier) which can reference rows? If so use that.

Comment: @Script47 that's what it was; no PK. As per [OP's comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844719/update-info-in-mysql-using-post#comment51611925_31844719)